# Why use aerial vehicles to establish a beachhead?

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow

There was some mention in the extras provided on the DVD that the film makers of *Edge of Tomorrow* chose Normandy as the point of the battle, to hark back to WWII.

In WWII, the allies were using ships to deliver troops, and determined there were only two ports/points in the British facing coast that could support an oceanic invasion. They were Normandy and Cherbourg.

But the troops in *Edge of Tomorrow* were traveling in air transport. At first I thought it was very clever to trick the Mimics into thinking they were going to invade by sea, thereby concentrating the defenders fire-power about those two likely entry points, only to see them fly straight into one of the two strongholds!

Given France has around 2000 miles of coastline, and maybe three quarters of that is on the north-western side facing Britain, why not attack at somewhere ***else*** along that coastline, or indeed, set the entry point as '10 kilometers inland' and fly straight over the beach?

Beyond the psychological advantage of 'We beat the defending forces before at Normandy, so let's do it again!' (which I think is pretty weak) what was the advantage of attacking at Normandy?

Comment: Because the film is very poorly written?

Comment: @JamesSheridan  Quite possibly, but I am hoping there is a logical reason I missed.

Comment: Technology maybe?  In WWII it would have been a terrible idea to parachute troops in.  In the movie they had zip lines? IDK

Comment: @DaveJohnson I think you missed the point!  I am not asking why the troops were delivered by air, but thy an air attack would start at Normandy.

Comment: "General Brigham: France. Satellites show minimum enemy movement down the coast, little resistance."  Kind of sounds like they were attacking elsewhere too?

Comment: @DaveJohnson Ah.. I'd forgotten that nugget, but it does sound familiar.  Interesting..

Comment: @DaveJohnson several tens of thousands of troops were parachuted over Normandy in the opening hours of D-day...

Comment: @jwenting Ha! Shows how much I know.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### They didn't depend solely upon aircraft. There were plenty of ships at sea visible in the beachhead landing at Normandy. It was not effectively shown in the landing sequence.

- Here is a screen-capture at time index 22:14 showing the battle from overhead. There are air-troop drop-ships, and hundreds of vessels along the coastline and further out to sea. But the scene lasts for four seconds so it is easy to overlook.

[image]

#### Why Normandy?

The United Defense Force attacks from the beach at Normandy for the same reason the Allies did in World War II. There wasn't any place that wasn't already overrun by the Mimics (Nazis).

[image]

- A review of a map early in movie shows the UDF in the same position as the Allies were during WWII, the entire country was covered by enemy forces with absolutely no place to land.
- At 1:06 seconds into the movie, we are shown several maps indicating in a five year window the Mimics have overrun the European continent. The UDF general says: "If we don't defeat them in France, we'll be fighting them in New York and then Tokyo."

[image]

- Even as the air strike invasion was occurring sitreps (situation updates) reported the fall of Germany to the Mimics. The entire European Union was under Mimic control. This was reported at 17:38 minutes into the movie. It is stated, if the battle was lost today, there would be no other battles for the European theater because the Mimics would take Great Britain in a day.
- There wasn't an advantage at Normandy except for the fact the beach is wide and the enemy wasn't fully entrenched yet. It allowed a wide distribution of troops and opportunity for successful drops.
- As for why they didn't fly over the beach? The enemy had effective anti-air technology making a flyover impossible. It is implied this area of France was the only place that wasn't completely under the Mimics control.

#### What You Might Not Have Noticed in the Chaos

There were surface ships on the scene. They appeared to be hovercraft whose purpose could have been equipment or support, they are not focused on during the conflict.

- You can see them behind Private Cage during the first chaotic landing sequence at time index 20:13 seconds. These ships certainly appear large enough to carry both troops, weapons, food, resources for an extended stay and maybe even small support vehicles.
- Two minutes later, the hoverships can be seen providing rocket fire support, possibly shelling the beach ahead of the troops, in the same way WWII ships provided shelling support.

[image]

#### Most Importantly

- The alien Mimics LEFT THE OPENING ON THE BEACH. This is revealed to us when Private Cage learns about the Mimics with Vertaski. The quote was  "An enemy that knows the future can't lose. We were allowed to win (at Verdun). This thing wants us to believe we can win. It wants us to throw everything we have into the invasion. Operation Downfall isn't our endgame. It's the enemy's." (time index 43:04)
- The Mimics want us to use everything we have so it left the door open at Normandy to entice us to do exactly what we did. Throw all of our technology and resources into the battle. Once it knows everything we are going to do, it will simply negate our strategy and overrun our forces.

#### The Mimics closed all the other doors on the French coastline because Normandy was a honeypot (a baited trap).